# How to check if PHP code is running from an IDE like PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I would like the PHP copy copied **AS-IS** to the production server and not run say a `Display()` function.  Currently I am having to edit/comment unwanted DEBUG code before uploading.

The `condition` in the sample code below could be something defined by the IDE like a flag DEBUG, I simply don't have enough experience with PHP.

```
function Display()
{
  if (condition) return ;  // skip no OUTPUT
  ...
  echo some variables...
}
```

Let me if something like this exists.

Or there is a better way to achieve this code management between DEBUG and LIVE on the server.

Thank you.

Comment: Define some constant (e.g. `DEV_MACHINE`) that you will have set to TRUE on your local/development environment and FALSE on your live server and check it. You can define it manually .. or based on some environment variable (detected at runtime: e.g. machine name, IP address whatever else). You can also use any package for `.env` files for that that will simplify this stuff (e.g. https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv). PhpStorm does not set any special variables or stuff like that for you.